# OS X Snow Leopard - Family pack: how does this work?

Tags: macos, license

we are a group of students, all having Mac OS X installed and we're planning to get the new OS X Snow Leopard (who doesn't :) ).
We would now have the option to buy the Family pack where Apple specifies

> By “household” we mean a person or
>   persons who share the same housing
>   unit such as a home, apartment, mobile
>   home, or condominium, including
>   **students who are primary residents of
>   that household but reside at a
>   separate on-campus location**. This
>   license does not extend to business or
>   commercial users

This would be fine for the moment, but I'm finishing my master probably next year, so what about that? Then this wouldn't hold any more of course.

Would that be fine? How does Apple verify this?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They don’t, as far as I know. It’s all on the honor system.

Answer (score 2):

What Apple are referring to in the highlighted passage is if you were at university or college but lived with your parents during holidays, you'd qualify under a license bought on your parents home.  This is actually a change since Tiger (starting with Leopard) as previously you wouldn't have been covered.

So as it's not about that paragraph, my view would be that you fall back to the standard definition and if you share a single "housing unit" you qualify.  Whether you think this applies may depend on exactly what your accommodation is but I'd suggest that if it has a single postal address, shared living space (kitchen, tv room and so on) and a lock which prevents general public access to these areas then you count.

I suspect that Apple would honour the license after you moved out as you'd bought it honestly and in good faith while qualifying.

But it's not checked by Apple, at least it wasn't in Leopard and as students who are giving them some money (more than most), I doubt you're high on their hit list for people to go after even if you had misunderstood it.

Note:  I'm not a lawyer and this isn't legal advice!

Answer (score 1):

As I remember it, Apple does not verify this.